# Sumar y restar input laravel en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

El problema que tengo es que cree una función para que me sume todos los campos y me lo muestre en un input para poder enviarlo y guardarlo el problema que tengo es que quiero sumar todos los campos y restarle el campo de retroactivo y ese resultado mostrarlo en el input neto pero no se si así como lo tengo esta bien de antemano gracias por algún ejemplo o sugerencia como hacerlo

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Colproin:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('colproin', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Sindicato:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('sindicato', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Dias_inca:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('dias_inca', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Tipo_inca:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('tipo_inca', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Incapacidad:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('incapacidad', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Reingreso:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('reingreso', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Otros:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('otros', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Embargo:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('embargo', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Ficohsa:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('ficohsa', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','onkeyup'=>'sumar()','placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Retroactivo:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::text('retroactivo', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero empleado','required'=> 'true']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('num_empleado', 'Neto:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!!Form::label('neto',$value=null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'spTotal','required'=>'true'])!!}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Esta es mi función donde realizo la suma si me esta sumando los campos que quiero pero no se como puedo restarle el retroactivo y mostrarlo en un `input` por que lo muestro pero en un `label` y ami me gustaría mostrarlo en un `input`.

```
<script>
    function sumar() {
        var total = 0;
        $(".form-control").each(function() {
            if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                total += 0;
            } else {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });

        //alert(total);
        document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
var total = 0;

$(".sumatorio").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
        total += 0;
    } else {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
});

$(".retroactivo").each(function() {
     if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
        total -= 0;
    } else {
        total -= parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
});


//alert(total);
$('#suma').val(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Sumatorio: </label><input type="number" class="sumatorio" name="sumatorio1" id="sumatorio1" value=10><br><br>
<label>Sumatorio: </label><input type="number" class="sumatorio" name="sumatorio2" id="sumatorio2" value=10><br><br>
<label>Sumatorio: </label><input type="number" class="sumatorio" name="sumatorio3" id="sumatorio3" value=10><br><br>
<label>Sumatorio: </label><input type="number" class="sumatorio" name="sumatorio4" id="sumatorio4" value=10><br><br>
<label>Retroactivo: </label><input type="number" class="retroactivo" name="retroactivo1" id="retroactivo1" value=5><br><br>
<label>Retroactivo: </label><input type="number" class="retroactivo" name="retroactivo2" id="retroactivo2" value=5><br><br>
<label>Suma: </label><input type="number" class="suma" name="suma" id="suma" value=0><br><br>
```